# Highchart trying to display map by state failed (R)

Tags: r

May I ask if I would like to display different colors according to the number of states on the map, but my map is as follows, only the overall map of Australia is not displayed according to different states.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(geojsonio)
library(highcharter)
 
dtstates1 <- read_csv('states_homeless1.csv')
ausgeojson <- GET("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/AUS.geo.json") %>%
  content() %>%
  fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE) %>%
  as.json()

names(dtstates1) <- c("hc-key", "value")
knitr::kable(head(dtstates1))


highchart(type = "map") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Homeless in Australia ") %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = "Homeless in Australia") %>%
  hc_add_series(mapData =ausgeojson, 
                showInLegend = TRUE,
                data = dtstates1,
                    name = "region",
                    value = "value",
                    joinBy = c("hc-key", "value")) %>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE)%>% 
  hc_colorAxis(auxpar = NULL)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zph8p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8iUV.png)

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi Peipei, I am not a highchart person (that is still on my to-do list, but the hc vizs are awesomw). When scanning over the code I wonder whether your mapdata comes with the regions? hc_add_series() seems to perform a join that could be empty/unsuccesful, if ausgeojson has nothing to join with. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `highcharter` - let me know if this will work for you.

First, get the data for Australia:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/au/au-all"))
```

Notice the data includes `hc-key` with values of `au-nt` and `au-wa` etc. - these do not match your data set of `dtstates1`. However, `woe-name` does match:

```
str(mapdata)

tibble [10 × 18] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ hc-group   : chr [1:10] "admin1" "admin1" "admin1" "admin1" ...
 $ hc-middle-x: num [1:10] 0.48 0.57 0.37 0.55 0.44 0.52 0.53 0.51 0.45 0.35
 $ hc-middle-y: num [1:10] 0.58 0.55 0.46 0.34 0.68 0.49 0.63 0.47 0.4 0.59
 $ hc-key     : chr [1:10] "au-nt" "au-wa" "au-ct" "au-sa" ...
 $ hc-a2      : chr [1:10] "NT" "WA" "CT" "SA" ...
 $ labelrank  : chr [1:10] "2" "2" "9" "2" ...
 $ hasc       : chr [1:10] "AU.NT" "AU.WA" "AU.CT" "AU.SA" ...
 $ woe-id     : chr [1:10] "2344701" "2344706" "1100968" "2344703" ...
 $ fips       : chr [1:10] "AS03" "AS08" "AS01" "AS05" ...
 $ postal-code: chr [1:10] "NT" "WA" "CT" "SA" ...
 $ name       : chr [1:10] "Northern Territory" "Western Australia" "Australian Capital Territory" "South Australia" ...
 $ country    : chr [1:10] "Australia" "Australia" "Australia" "Australia" ...
 $ type-en    : chr [1:10] "Territory" "State" "Territory" "State" ...
 $ longitude  : chr [1:10] "133.78" "121.646" "148.983" "135.783" ...
 $ woe-name   : chr [1:10] "Northern Territory" "Western Australia" "Canberra" "South Australia" ...
 $ latitude   : chr [1:10] "-20.1026" "-25.8483" "-35.4618" "-29.6504" ...
 $ woe-label  : chr [1:10] "Northern Territory, AU, Australia" "Western Australia, AU, Australia" NA "South Australia, AU, Australia" ...
 $ type       : chr [1:10] "Territory" "State" "Territory" "State" ...
```

For this example, I recreated your data frame with names of states/territories (and set column name to `woe-name`):

```
dtstates1 <- data.frame(
  key = c("New South Wales", "Queensland", "South Australia", "Tasmania", "Victoria", "Western Australia", "Australia Capital Territory", "Northern Territory"),
  value = c(23148, 12303, 6279, 2507, 32582, 6546, 1780, 3256)
)

names(dtstates1) <- c("woe-name", "value")
```

Then you can map as follows, using `woe-name` for `joinBy`:

```
hcmap("countries/au/au-all", showInLegend = TRUE,
      data = dtstates1,
      values = "value",
      joinBy = "woe-name") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Homeless in Australia ") %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = "Homeless in Australia")
```

**Map**

[image: map of australia in highcharts]